# How to fil SQL table from DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql

I have to fill SQL table from DataGridView. The problem consists in fact, that I have a bunch of tables with different count of columns and I cant write a simple script to fill it "row by row", so I decided to push data by DataTable, but I get an error

> The table type parameter "@data" must have a valid type name

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        sqlConnection.Open();

        var dt = new DataTable();

        dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;

        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"DELETE FROM [DB].[dbo].[" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()+ "]; INSERT INTO [DB].[dbo].[" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()+ "] VALUES (@data)",sqlConnection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", dt);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), ex.Source.ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlReader != null)
                sqlReader.Close();
        }
}
```

`comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()` returns table name.

First part of query is deleting table, as otherwise it will duplicate unchanged info, after this I'm sending it back as dataGridView has all data

Comment: When you run with DataTable, consider using Stored Procedure with param is DataTableType, it solves all your problem.

Comment: @TấnNguyên So how I have to set type of it `CREATE PROCEDURE LoadData @table [TYPE]`?

Comment: `CREATE TYPE YourTableType AS TABLE()` like create table script. Then `CREATE PROCEDURE LoadData @table YourTableType` [For more information](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/user-defined-table-types-and-table-valued-parameters/)

Comment: @TấnNguyên Does it means that I have to create few procedures as I have different count of columns in my tables, or there is some way to make dynamic for any count of columns? As I see i have to put columns with its types after `CREATE TYPE YourTableType AS TABLE()`

Comment: The TableType could be generic for reuse and no need to full of columns like destination table. Then you could pass the table name as second parameter in your procedure to coordinate what table should be inserted. But if you have more complicated DataTableType, consider one procedure for one table type. It's your choice for future implementation.

Comment: I have worked for almost 100 stored procedure with 100 table type to insert into SQL, it's still ok and easier for tracking what fail will come.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.8) ?

The tricky part would be [matching column names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopycolumnmapping?view=netframework-4.8)

If you cannot use that there is an option to use [Table Valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)

Also instead of `DELETE FROM [dbo].[table]` you might be interested in `TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[table]` command